# Текст не переносится на новую строку

Tags: html, css

У меня имеется некоторый `p` который находится в блоке
(1 скрин)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с фиксированной шириной,ему задан `word-break: break-all` но перенос все равно не работает

Comment: Это всё конечно хорошо, но лучше предоставьте код с которым надо работать, иначе в ответе придётся прислать не код решения, а его скриншот.

Comment: @ΝNL993 простой див с шириной в 100% и тег без стилей, нет смысла предоставлять код

Comment: я и удивлен что он не переносится, хоть и должен

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в стиле. Нужно написать так `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: тут ошибся на SO, IDE все верно написала, не помогает

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Тогда покажите минимизированный пример где отражается ваша проблема.